# Redirect log to file before process finished

Tags: python

test.py (work):

```
import time

_, a, b = [1, 2, 3]
print a
print b
```

run the code: python test.py > test.log

you will get the log in test.log

test.py (not work):

```
import time

_, a, b = [1, 2, 3]
print a
print b

while True:
    time.sleep(5)
```

But this one you get None in the log.

How do I get log before the program finished, without the python log module(just use the redirect '>')?

Comment: Lookup "flush output". I marked your question as a duplicate of another one. Though it said "screen" and not file, it's actually the same thing from your program's perspective.

Comment: `import sys; sys.stdout.flush()`

Comment: the fifth answer is worked for file,but not accepted in that question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Python buffers `stdout` by default so the log gets written to disk in chunks. You can turn off the buffering a few different ways, here are two. You can use the `-u` option when you call the script, ie:

```
python -u test.py
```

You can use the enviornment varialbe `PYTHONUNBUFFERED`:

```
export PYTHONUNBUFFERED=true
python test.py
```